JSON File terror
I opened a json file "ac_def.json" in my visual studio and it is a total mess out here. I don't understand what is going on. I don't what is happening. I want to make it normal. What do I doHere is the error
So I opened a file in a apk, and the code looks like that. I'm presuming that a code that is not appropriate to the format was inserted, so that's why the json file was like that

you have to provide how you creating json, json file should be a text, this looks like binary

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
